# Find SonicWall Admin login's using splunk

Tags: splunk, sonicwall

I would like to use splunk to report on when the Admnin credentials are used to login to the Sonicwall. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://software.sonicwall.com/Manual/232-001835-00_Rev_A_SonicOS_Log_Event_Reference_Guide.pdf , it looks like the log message for an administrator login is
"Administrator login allowed"

So in Splunk, you would just need to search for the following to get all the events

```
index=sonicwall "Administrator login allowed"
```

You may also want Administrator login failures, which are "Administrator login denied due to bad credentials"

If you want to put this in a report, something like the following should suffice

```
index=sonicwall "Administrator login allowed" OR "Administrator login denied due to bad credentials" | eval type=if(match(_raw,"allowed"),"success","failure") | timechart count by type
```

Comment: I thank you for that, I did notice that I am getting 2 msg "vpn zone administrator login allowed" and "administrator login allowed".. however the "m value" of 29 is specific to the "administrator login allowed" so I used that instead. Thank you for the input and help I was able to get the search I was looking for.